# Mockito WrongTypeOfReturnValue Iterable instead of List

Tags: java, mockito

I use JpaRepository to save collections to my DB. Here's the method's declaration:

```
<S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);
```

In my tests I use `returnsFirstArg` as answer like this:

```
doAnswer(returnsFirstArg()).when(userRepository)
        .save(anyListOf(User.class));
```

So I want to return given collection without saving. I can't return `null` because I test the following code:

```
return userRepository.save(users);
```

and I should then make assertions on the result.
Mocking gives me the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:  The argument
>   of type 'Iterable' cannot be returned because the following  method
>   should return the type 'List'  -> userRepositorty bean.save()
>
> The reason for this error can be :
>   1. The wanted argument position is incorrect.
>   2. The answer is used on the wrong interaction.
>
> Position of the wanted argument is 0 and the possible argument indexes
>   for this method are :
>       [0] Iterable

How can I solve this issue?
*Mockito 1.10.19*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as the error message suggests, the first argument is an `Iterable`, not a `List`. `returnsFirstArg`, unfortunately, doesn't let you downcast the argument, even though you are actually passing a `List`.

Surprisingly enough, if you just naively implement this behavior with an `Answer` of your own, it works just fine:

```
doAnswer(i -> i.getArguments()[0])
   .when(userRepository)
   .save(anyListOf(String.class));
```

It isn't elegant, but it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't get why `i.getArguments()[0]` works and `returnsFirstArgument` not. I thought they're the same.